# Javascript getting Values from tagged data

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get string data out of the following type of string array where the Tag equals "UNSORTED"

```
"<UNSORTED><NAME_NO>999</NAME_NO></UNSORTED> <OTHER ID="075">OTHER</OTHER>"


"<UNSORTED><LASTNAME_NO>999</LASTNAME_NO></UNSORTED> <UNSORTED><TOWN_NO>1000</TOWN_NO></UNSORTED>"
```

In the first Example I want to extract 999

and in the second example I want to extract 999 and 1000

Any idea how I can do this in Javascript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expression, like this

```
var name = x.match(/<name_no>(\d+)<\/name_no>/i);
var town = y.match(/<town_no>(\d+)<\/town_no>/i);
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/nomaho/1/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 0):

You can try regex like:

```
var captured = str.match(<UNSORTED>[^\d]*(\d*)<\/)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/cT9tD6/1

Answer (score 0):

As this is XML, you can use an in-memory document using [document.implementation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.implementation) and [XPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_XPath):

```js
var str = '<UNSORTED><LASTNAME_NO>999</LASTNAME_NO></UNSORTED> <UNSORTED><TOWN_NO>1000</TOWN_NO></UNSORTED>';

// create a document in memory
var doc = document.implementation.createDocument('','');

// create a dummy node to store str in and add to our document
var root = doc.createElement('root');
root.innerHTML = str;
doc.appendChild(root);

// run xpath to find all the children of <UNSORTED> nodes
var unsorteds = doc.evaluate( '//UNSORTED/*', doc, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );

// iterate through the matches and build results
var res, results = [];
while (res = unsorteds.iterateNext()) {
    // optionally ingore blank tags
    if(res.textContent.trim().length > 0) {
        // add the textContent of the node to the results array
        results.push(res.textContent);
    }
}

// log results
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = results.join('\n');
```

```html
<textarea id="result" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by matching any child of `UNSORTED` that ends with `_NO`. That way, you can have any tag name:

```
var results = [];
$("UNSORTED").children().filter(function(){
    return (/.+_NO/.test(this.tagName));
}).each(function(){
    results.push($(this).text());
});

console.log(results); // ["999", "999", "1000"]
```